# How to query from ListColumn[String] in cassandra using phantom

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am new to cassandra (started learning on my own interest few days back) and looking for help for the below problem.

I have a Cassandra table "User" and a ListColumn "interests extends ListColumn[String]".
Now, I want to fetch all users with an interest, say "playing".

like: select from user where interests.contains("playing")!
I scanned through the ListColumn api but not able to find any. Also, searched in google but no such helpful posts.

Any help guys please... Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Would be that the only condition in your query?

Comment: Some other field may include in the query... but for now, the single condition would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is `contains` among [operators](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/4a919733614cb838231ef70acb734275fe9f7b30/phantom-dsl/src/main/scala/com/websudos/phantom/builder/ops/ImplicitMechanism.scala#L94) and here is [an example](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/4164fee5927e9f1b520f2729ab6f7ed59f55afe6/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/websudos/phantom/builder/query/db/specialized/IndexedCollectionsTest.scala#L57) how to use it. It looks like that it should work as any other operator, so just go for `database.userTable.select.where(_.interests contains "playing").fetch()` - of course, depending on your conventions.

Comment: Thanks a lot... appreciated your help :)

Comment: Thanks a lot... Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a secondary index on a collection column, which only works with a `Set` column, and not with a `List`.

Bottom line:

```
object interests extends SetColumn[String](this) with Index[Set[String]]
```

And then you can execute the following:

```
select.where(_.interests contains "test").fetch()
```

You can also use multiple restrictions if you allow filtering.

```
select.where(_.interests contains "test")
  .and(_.interests contains "test2")
  .allowFiltering()
  .fetch()
```

The above will only match if both interests are found in a record.

Comment: Thanks a lot... appreciated your help :)